# Is comma separated return values necessary in this c++ extended euclid function?

Tags: c++

Today as I am revising about the extended euclidean algorithm, and I stumble a code library that does this:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
#define rep(i, a, b) for (int i = a; i < (b); ++i)
#define all(x) begin(x), end(x)
#define sz(x) (int)(x).size()
typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int, int> pii;
typedef vector<int> vi;

ll euclid(ll a, ll b, ll &x, ll &y) {
  if (!b) {
    return x = 1, y = 0, a;
  }
  ll d = euclid(b, a % b, y, x);
  return y -= a / b * x, d;
}
```

I am curious that the return type is a `long long`, and from my initial search, in a multiple comma return in c++, only the right value is kept and returned. So the question is, why does the author of this function still want to `x = 1, y = 0` or `y -= a / b * x` on the left hand side of the same return line?

Comment: To change the values of `x` and `y`. They are passed by reference.

Comment: `x` and `y` are references so that code is making modifications to those variables. Writing it that way just makes it confusing IMO. Of course, any time I see the silly macros that folks like to use in so called competitive programming I know I'm not looking at a work of art.

Comment: The return statement could've been written as two separate statements `y -= a / b * x;` and `return d;`, which is more conventional and readable than trying to fit as many operations into every statement as possible. The macros and typedefs that obfuscates the code is also a sign that the author does not prioritize readability.

Comment: Not related to the main question, but for people reading the code: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: As the author seems to limit at maximum the number of characters in the code, I would suggest to maximize this and remove all those spaces between characters, and avoid the overlong `ll` type name by using just `l`.

Comment: *"why does the author of this function still want to [...]?"* -- this is just speculation (so not a real answer), but perhaps the author wanted to confuse someone known as "Sheen An" (along with anyone else attempting to read the code)?

Comment: This seems to be a perfect example of how **not** to write code. Like defining a bunch of macros to make the code shorter (but unreadable), and then not use them. So in fact make the code longer!

Comment: haha @JaMiT that was a funny comment, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This return line

```cpp
return y -= a / b * x, d;
```

does indeed only return the `d` via return value, true.
It does however also update the two reference parameters `x` and `y`,
which can be seen as part of the value-returning.

It could be done in a preceeding line.
That would avoid the false impression that the author tries to return more than one value, which as you correctly mention, C++ does not support.